# Access range input value to display it on top of slider

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I want to use a range slider to select a value and render this value on top of the range selector in Angular.
My html code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="range">Raio: {{raio}} metros</label>
      <input type="range" min="100" max="2000" step="100" 
      oninput="rangeChange(this.value)"
             class="form-control-range" id="range">
</div>
```

In my component.ts i have the following function:

```
export class LugaresComponent implements OnInit {
raio = 200;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

rangeChange(value) {
    this.raio=value;
    console.log(this.raio)
    }
}
```

When I select a value on the range input I am receiving the following error on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: rangeChange is not defined
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: events use this notation `(input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to use oninput as an event, with *()* and then pass the event to the function

```
<input type="range" min="100" max="2000" step="100" (oninput)="rangeChange($event)" />

rangeChange(event) {
   this.raio = event.target.value;
}
```

But it would be better to use data binding via ngModel, there is no need to handle the event if you only need to bind the value from the input to a component's property

```
<input type="range" min="100" max="2000" step="100" [(ngModel)]="raio" />
```